# What's the best way to add custom HTML in the middle of a form with many fields?

Tags: django

I have a model with 40+ fields and a ModelForm for interacting with it. In my template I'm doing

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label }} {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to customize the final HTML - insert separators after some fields, a div after another and so on. What's the best way to do this? I thought of two ways and am wondering if I missed something more elegant:

1. The obvious one - instead of iterating over fields in the form, manually put all fields and whatever HTML I desire between them. The downside is that this duplicates the work of listing all fields in the model and requires manual adjustments if I ever change the set of the fields I want.
2. Do something like this:

   ```
   for field in form
      render field
      if field.name in fields_i_want_to_put_a_br_after
          <br>
      if field.name in fields_i_want_to_put_a_div_after
          <div>
   ```

Comment: I've used the first pattern a few times. Another possibility is to create widgets for some of the fields

Comment: You could add `attrs` in the Field Widget and add the `<br>` via css rules.

Comment: you mean you want to add an element after - for example - a specific field?? you can use if statement in the template..

Comment: @schwobaseggl How? ::after/before cannot be used to add HTML, only text.