# Adding a new ManyToMany relationship in a form?

Tags: django

Django newbie here. I keep encountering the exact same design paradigm, which seems like it should be common for everyone, yet can't find out how it's supposed to be resolved.

Picture the following ManyToMany relationships:

- An organization could have many members; each person could be a member of many organizations
- An organization could manage many objects.  An object could be in use by multiple organizations.  The same applies to the relationship between people and objects.
- An organization, person, or object could have multiple media elements (photos, videos, etc) of it, and a single media element could be tagged with numerous organizations, people, or objects

Nothing unusual. But how does a site user add a new person, organization, or object?  It seems that if someone is filling out an "add an organization" form, in addition to choosing from existing people, objects, media, etc there should be a button for "new member", "new object", "new photo", etc, and this should take you to the forms for creating new members, objects, media, etc. And when they're done, it should go back to the previous page - whose form filled-out form entries should persist, and the newly created entry should be listed in its respective ManyToMany field.

The problem is, I don't know how to do this. I don't know how one would add a button in the middle of a form, and can't seem to find anything to clarify how to do it. I assume it would need to be a submit button, with a different name / id or some other way so that views.py can treat it differently, via flagging an "incomplete" record in the database. And the new form will need to be passed information about what page it needs to go back to when it's submitted.

Am I thinking about this correctly? If so, then I think the only knowledge I lack is how to add a second submit button in a form and how to recognize its usage in views.py.

If I'm not thinking about this correctly, however, please suggest an alternative paradigm that you think makes more sense  :)  This is my first Django project, so I'm learning as I do it.

ED: I'm thinking maybe instead of using {{ form.as_p }} to display it, I need to iterate over fields and use some logic to add the extra submit button in the middle as html: [What's the best way to add custom HTML in the middle of a form with many fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710049/whats-the-best-way-to-add-custom-html-in-the-middle-of-a-form-with-many-fields)

Then I'll just need to figure out a way to detect which submit button was used and put some logic behind it to handle partially-submitted forms, redirecting to a form to create the relation, and then redirecting back on submit... I can probably figure this out...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend is to define your models. Lay them all out with the attributes you require. That'll be the foundation for everything else you want to accomplish. You can do everything you mentioned with Django... it's just a matter of coding it. As far as I know you would need to create each model instance separately, and then you can refer to already created instances in the create form for the Organization model for example. I would look into the docs for generic views that help you create objects easily. Then you can link to other create forms if you wish. I don't know how you can create multiple instances of different models in one form, and I don't think it would be the best way to do things even if you can. Here's an example of a model, a create form, a create view, and corresponding url:

```
# models.py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

# forms.py
class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ('name',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrganizationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].required  = True

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(OrganizationForm, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')

# views.py
class OrganizationCreateView(CreateView): # inherits from CreateView
    form_class = OrganizationForm
    template_name = 'create_org.html'
    success_url = 'success'

    def form_valid(self, form): # validate the form and save the model instance
        org = form.save(commit=False)
        org.save()
        return redirect(reverse('redirect_url'))

# urls.py
from Project.apps.app_name import views as app_views

app_name = 'app_name'

urlpatterns = [
           url(r'^create_org/$', app_views.OrganizationCreateView.as_view(), name='create_org'), # as_view() is used for class based views

# create_org.html

<form method="post">

 {% crsf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <a href="{% url 'app_name:create_person' %}>Create person</a> # You can link to other create views, and just style the link as a button.
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Models are already laid out, and the idea was to have a button that brings you to a new form (aka submits the old one flagged as "unfinished"), then returns you to the old one when it's done. But I don't know how to add what would effectively be a second submit button in the middle of the form, and to handle the result. Your adding of a link below form.as_p will always put the link at the bottom, not next to the widget for the ManyToMany field.

Comment: @KarenRei - You should post your code. If you show us where you're at and what you've tried then it makes it easier to help. When you say 'not next to the widget for the ManyToMany field' I've no idea how to help or what else to suggest because there isn't any code to work with.